# USAT, Arora Barak's book

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, satisfiability, polynomial-time, 3-sat

[Here](http://download.library1.org/get/3917534DE1C59122745CE3A45F6B6A10/Sanjeev%20Arora%2C%20Boaz%20Barak-Computational%20complexity_%20A%20modern%20approach-Cambridge%20University%20Press%20%282009%29.pdf) on the page 354 Arora and Barak write below the shaded area

"but in fact $f(\phi)$ $\notin SAT$"

and not

"but in fact $f(\phi) \in SAT$"

While in the last line of the shaded area they write

$Pr[f(\phi)\in SAT]=0$

Shouldn't there be in that last line also **not**:

$Pr[f(\phi)\notin SAT]=0$

?

Comment: You might have found a typo. If the text makes sense with your correction, but doesn't make sense without your correction, then it's a typo. They happen. Humans are not infallible.

Comment: The thing is that I'm not sure that it is a typo and how it should be corrected.In the corollary 17.20 on page 355 4th row in that corollary there is something similar: $$A(\phi)\in \oplus \text{SAT}$$ I do not believe that they would make the same typo 2 times in a row. Can someone reliable please have a look at these two lines of the book and let me know what is right and what is wrong?

Comment: Part of the skill involved in reading papers and monographs (and, in this case, textbooks) is acknowledging the existence of mistakes, identifying them, and, when possible, correcting them.

Comment: Of course. But can someone tell me how these 2 lines (4th line of corollary 17.20 and last line of the shadowed area on page 354) should look like. Actually I do not know what is correct and what is my incapability.

Comment: Your problem only makes sense for people in possession of a copy of the Arora–Barak textbook. Perhaps you could provide a self-contained version of your doubt?

Comment: A pdf copy is given in the very first word of my question: [Here](http://download.library1.org/get/81DE8572F1A8D2360452D01721C18507/Sanjeev%20Arora%2C%20Boaz%20Barak-Computational%20complexity_%20A%20modern%20approach-Cambridge%20University%20Press%20%282009%29.pdf)

Comment: It doesn't match your actual references.

Comment: The link location is incorrect?? It works for me fine.

Comment: It's a different version of the textbook. It's also likely illegal.

Comment: I use it only for personal need and it matches the page number 354 for me...